# Test looking for enum class inside src/main rather than src/test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm a bit confused about the visibility of classes between the src/test and src/main directories. I have an enum created under both packages, but with an extra case when under the test folder to allow me to test for a negative scenario. However, IntelliJ gives me an error as if looking for that extra case under the enum in the main folder (the test compiles and passes though). On the same note, when I inspect the usages for the enum inside the main folder, it will show also the test directory. Not sure how to specify I want to use one over the other as I'd have imagined that the one from src/test would take precedence over src/main for code under that same src/test directory?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks very much.

*UPDATE*

Renaming the enum to have different names wouldn't be accepted by the calling method.

[image]

Comment: If set up correctly main classes cannot see test classes

Comment: What is the test case supposed to test? Calling the oauth manager with this invalid client cannot happen, that's pretty much what the `enum` is for. The only reasonable test case is calling it with `null`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The use case is unlikely to happen and this test had been added mainly for coverage as our code had a switch throwing an exception for the default case. This has been removed now with the update to java 17. However, I'm still not sure why IntelliJ wasn't finding the class inside the right package. Maybe a bug or weird behaviour, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your imports it probably imported the Main class first and is trying to find the extra addition in that class instead of the other class. you can either manually add the test class to your imports (not recommended) or, what I would do, is change the name of the test class to have Test at the end (I do this for all my test classes to prevent this kind of problem). So in the test, you can call `ClientTest.ANY_OTHER` if you want to call a different input from that class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added a screenshot showing what happens when they are named different.